# Why Java will not allow to use access modifiers in loops?

Tags: java, loops, final, access-modifiers

```
for(public int i=0;i<10;i++) {

        System.out.println(i);

        }
for(private int i=0;i<10;i++) {

        System.out.println(i);

    }
```

Eclipse says only final is permitted.

Comment: Because local variables can never be accessed outside the scope they're declared in.

Comment: What would you expect the semantics of a public variable declared in a loop to be?

Comment: The same question I asked the guy who asked this question to me, but he said you find it. Also he asked me which is the default modifier for local variables

Comment: You're not in very talented company then, are you?

Comment: The question was asked in my Job interview :P

Comment: Is there a reason to declare an access controller when declaring int i?

Comment: Maybe the question was just designed to see how you respond to unexpected questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** we need to know that what is the need of Access modifiers.
An access modifier restricts the access of a class, constructor, data member and method in another class.

But when we declare a variable or anything inside a loop their scope/use is restricted only to that loop. 
That means we can use these variables only inside that loop. We can't use these variables outside of that loop.
(SUN people who wrote java have restricted it).

so if we don't use loop variables outside of loop then what is the need to use Access modifiers inside loop. That's why java doesn't allow it.